# How do I make Excel recognize empty cells after Paste Special-Values copied from formulas?

Tags: excel, copy-paste

If I have a column of data with some missing entries, Excel recognizes those cells as empty. For example, if I press ctrl-down in A2, the cursor stops in A5 at the edge of the block of entries.  That behavior is exactly as expected (highlighted Column A in the pic).

If I create a column of conditional formulas that leaves some entries entries apparently blank, Excel recognizes that all cells contain entries (the formulas) and ctrl-down goes directly to the end of the column. That behavior is also exactly as expected (Column B in the pic; B6 appears empty but contains a formula).

But if I copy column B with its formulas (with apparently empty cell) and do Paste Special/Values in C, Excel treats Column C as full. Ctrl-down in C2 goes to the end of the column, skipping over the seemingly empty cell (highlighted Column C in the pic; ctrl-down goes all the way to C8, skipping the "empty" cell C6).

Column D shows that Excel recognizes A6 and C6 are equal, but treats them differently.

[image: Spreadsheet showing different ctrl-down behavior in Columns A and C]

Is there a way to Paste Special so that Excel recognizes that cell as empty? If I just delete the empty cell C6, Excel again knows it's empty, and treats it as such. In this example it's trivial, but with thousands of rows the behavior is frustrating. I rely on the ctrl-arrow keys to navigate large datasets.

A VBA solution (below) is to read the selected column(s) into a variant, then turn around and write the variant directly back into the column. That restores the empty cells so that Excel recognizes them. It works, but I work on multiple PCs. That makes using a VBA subroutine awkward, since I have to locate the sub on the network drive from every PC to be able to use it. Is there an easier way around this? Does Paste Special have an option that I've never found regarding empty cells? A native Excel option would be preferable to this sub. Appreciate any suggestions!

```
Sub RestoreEmptyCells()
    Dim vntContents As Variant, rngColumn As Range
    
    Set rngColumn = Selection  ' Use Selection to keep it simple
    vntContents = rngColumn  ' Read the column into a variant
    rngColumn = vntContents  ' Read the variant back into the column
    Set rngColumn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Put your code in an AddIn, installed in a path in your roaming profile.  That way it will be accessible everywhere

Comment: That's a good idea. Unfortunately, I neglected to add the reason I work on different PCs is that I often support other users, so we're usually on their PCs under their usernames. My roaming profile won't be accessible.

Comment: I've solved part of the problem, cleaning up empty cells. I just discovered the Find dialog allows searching for empties. In the dialog, delete anything in the "Find what" box, and check the "Match entire cell contents" box. Find All then creates an easy to navigate list of the empty cells.